# Find value in different row and get it to particular row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have various columns in an `SQL` table in column `C` I have `ID` that fits one of the rows but from column `ID`. when I find this row I need to get value from column B and show it as separate table.

Example:

```
ID B           C 
1  text        3
2  text 
3  value2get
```

Now I need to

- Get value from column C (3)
- Find which row has this value (3) as its ID
- Create new column and put the value from column B to separated table

So the result shall be:

```
ID B    C NewColumn 
1  text 3 value2get
```

I'm sorry for this table structure.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand better:

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.B, T1.C, T2.B as NewColumn
FROM yourTable T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN yourTable T2
    ON T1.c = T2.id
WHERE T1.c IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry for too chatty comment, but thank you, you saved my day and obviously time. This works well!

Comment: @Marek: Haver a nice day ;)